# I want to get name of focused textbox controls that I created at run-time in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, windows-phone-8.1

I am adding got focus event mytextboxes when I create them

```
                `TextBox Xi = new TextBox();
                Xi.Name = "X" + i.ToString();
                Xi.Width = 10;
                Xi.Height = 10;
                Xi.GotFocus += Xi_GotFocus;`
```

But I can't get focused control's name

`void Xi_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`

is there any way get the name of these controls ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below mentioned code

```
void Xi_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    string name = t.Name;
}
```

Comment: @OknAkdgn:don't forgot to accept it so other can use it :)

Comment: never forget i had to wait 8 min after answer now i accepted thank you again :)